# Making a predictive text algorithm go faster

Tags: c#, regex, windows, backgroundworker

I am working on a windows phone dialler app and I have implemented prediction text in my app. When user taps on keypad, contacts that match input are generated. Prediction is too slow, it also blocks my main thread that's why I have implemented BackGroundWorker But still having problems with the performance
My code is:

```
private void dialer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.DialerText = dialer.Text;
        if(!bw1.IsBusy)
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync();
     }
 void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    { 1, "" },
    { 2, "[abcABC]" },
    { 3, "[defDEF]" },
    { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
    { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
    { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
    { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
    { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
    { 9, "[wxyzWXYZ]" },
    { 0, "" },
};
            var enteredDigits = DialerText;
            var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
            var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
            regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);
            MainPage.pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();

            MainPage.pattern = ".*" + MainPage.pattern + ".*";


        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
        }

    }
void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchListbox.ItemsSource = listobj.FindAll(x => x.PhoneNumbers.Any(a=>a.Contains(MainPage.DialerText)) | Regex.IsMatch(x.FirstName, MainPage.pattern));
    }
```

BackGroundWorker also blocking my main thread, hence when I tap on the keypad there's a lag while input values are added to the TextBox. I want to add input to the TextTox without any lag, how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You can grab a real speed-up here by moving away from exhaustive searches of the entire wordlist and instead, putting your words into a more efficient data-structure.

For lightning fast lookups over any size of word list (but more expensive in terms of memory), you should build a tree structure that contains your entire word list.

The root node represents zero dialled digits, and it is connected to (up to) ten more nodes, where the edges connecting the nodes represent one of the possible numbers pressed for 0 to 9.

Each node then contains the possible words that can be formed from the path taken through the tree from the root node, where the path is representative of the numbers pressed.

This means that a search no longer requires iterating the entire word list and can be completed in very few operations.

Here's the concept in practice with a [370000 word-list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt) I found on the web. Search takes around about 0.02ms on my desktop. Nice and fast. Seems to take about ~50MB in memory.

```
void Main()
{
    var rootNode = new Node();

    //probably a bad idea, better to await in an async method
    LoadNode(rootNode).Wait(); 

    //let's search a few times to get meaningful timings    
    for(var i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        //"acres" in text-ese (specifically chosen for ambiguity)
        var searchTerm = "22737";
        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var wordList = rootNode.Search(searchTerm);
        Console.WriteLine("Search complete in {0} ms", 
                        sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds);
        Console.WriteLine("Search for {0}:", searchTerm);
        foreach(var word in wordList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Found {0}", word);
        }   
    }
    GC.Collect();
    var bytesAllocated = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);
    Console.WriteLine("Allocated {0} bytes", bytesAllocated);
}

async Task LoadNode(Node rootNode)
{
    var wordListUrl = 
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dwyl/english-words/master/words_alpha.txt";
    Console.WriteLine("Loading words from {0}", wordListUrl);
    using(var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    using(var stream = await httpClient.GetStreamAsync(wordListUrl))
    using(var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        var wordCount = 0;
        string word;
        while( (word = await reader.ReadLineAsync()) != null )
        {
            word = word.ToLowerInvariant();
            if(!Regex.IsMatch(word,@"^[a-z]+$"))
            {
                continue;
            }
            rootNode.Add(word);
            wordCount++;
        }   
        Console.WriteLine("Loaded {0} words", wordCount);
    }
}

class Node
{
    static Dictionary<int, string> digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
        { 1, "" },
        { 2, "abcABC" },
        { 3, "defDEF" },
        { 4, "ghiGHI" },
        { 5, "jklJKL" },
        { 6, "mnoMNO" },
        { 7, "pqrsPQRS" },
        { 8, "tuvTUV" },
        { 9, "wxyzWXYZ" },
        { 0, "" }};
    static Dictionary<char,int> letterMap;
    static Node()
    {
        letterMap = digitMap
            .SelectMany(m => m.Value.Select(c=>new {ch = c, num = m.Key}))
            .ToDictionary(x => x.ch, x => x.num);
    }

    List<string> words = new List<string>();

    //the edges collection has exactly 10 
    //slots which represent the numbers [0-9]
    Node[] edges = new Node[10];

    public IEnumerable<string> Words{get{
        return words;
    }}

    public void Add(string word, int pos = 0)
    {
        if(pos == word.Length)
        {
            if(word.Length > 0)
            {
                words.Add(word);
            }
            return;
        }
        var currentChar = word[pos];
        int edgeIndex = letterMap[currentChar];
        if(edges[edgeIndex] == null)
        {
            edges[edgeIndex] = new Node();
        }
        var nextNode = edges[edgeIndex];
        nextNode.Add(word, pos+1);
    }

    public Node FindMostPopulatedNode()
    {
        Stack<Node> stk = new Stack<Node>();
        stk.Push(this);
        Node biggest = null;
        while(stk.Any())
        {
            var node = stk.Pop();
            biggest = biggest == null
               ? node
               : (node.words.Count > biggest.words.Count
                   ? node
                   : biggest);
            foreach(var next in node.edges.Where(e=>e != null))
            {
                stk.Push(next);
            }
        }
        return biggest;
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> Search(string numberSequenceString)
    {
        var numberSequence = numberSequenceString
                               .Select(n => int.Parse(n.ToString()));
        return Search(numberSequence);
    }
    private IEnumerable<string> Search(IEnumerable<int> numberSequence)
    {
        if(!numberSequence.Any())
        {
            return words;
        }
        var first = numberSequence.First();
        var remaining = numberSequence.Skip(1);
        var nextNode = edges[first];
        if(nextNode == null)
        {
            return Enumerable.Empty<string>();
        }
        return nextNode.Search(remaining);
    }
}
```

Comment: @thewarri0r9 I've just finished for the day, so I might give this a punt for leisure purposes :)

Comment: @thewarri0r9 You owe me ;)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, I'm still trying to implement this in my project. Hope this works :)

Comment: Can you please tell me how to implement that in my project? I have list of contacts, so how do I match the it with the wordList?

Comment: Wonderful response. I wonder, how might this be effectively implemented in a client/server architecture? Persistence between requests in Dot Net still leaves something to be desired IMO, if it didn't cost so much to generate the tree, I would love to use this method on the server...

Comment: @BryanRayner, I'm currently doing something very similar with a different (but very large) [datastructure](https://github.com/biggyspender/BkTree). We do this in Azure with Cloud Service worker roles running WebAPI through OWIN. This gives very tight control of the hosting environment without all the apppool/timeout/recycling that IIS imposes on you. The data structure is initialized at startup, and restarts don't really happen anymore.

Comment: This is a great solution. it could work well with a directed graph database, There are many of them, like Neo4j, but it's easy to roll your own.

Answer (score 2):

There is a number of optimizations you could make to improve the speed:

- Adding `.*` prefix and suffix to your regex pattern is not necessary, because `IsMatch` will detect a match anywhere in a string
- Using a local `Dictionary<int,string>` for parts of your pattern can be replaced by a `static` array
- Converting digits to `int`s can be replaced with subtraction
- The `foreach` loop and appending could be replaced by `string.Join`

Here is how:

```
private static string[] digitMap = new[] {
    ""
,   "",           "[abcABC]", "[defDEF]"
,   "[ghiGHI]",   "[jklJKL]", "[mnoMNO]"
,   "[pqrsPQRS]", "[tuvTUV]", "[wxyzWXYZ]"
};
void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
    try {
        MainPage.pattern = string.Join("", DialerText.Select(c => digitMap[c-'0']));
    } catch (Exception f) {
        //  MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: It does make it fast, I think if I can add searchListBox.Itemsource code in my doWork then it'd be more faster but it doesn't work that way (may be because backGroundWorker can't get access to the SearchListBox). Any way to do so?

Comment: @thewarri0r9 I never programmed a windows phone, so I am not sure if I understand your comment. You may want to ask a separate question about filtering list box in response to user input, without explaining how you come up with the pattern (you can use this method as a "black box" that takes `DialerText` and provides `MainPage.pattern`).

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the reason for the blocking is that your background worker thread doesn't actually do very much.

I expect the `bw1_RunWorkerCompleted` method (which gets run on the MAIN thread after the background worker has completed) is far more long-running! Can you move some (all?) of this code into the bw1_DoWork method instead? Obviously "listobj" would have to be accessible to the background thread though - just pass it into your delegate and access it by the DoWorkEventArgs.Argument property for this...

```
private void dialer_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MainPage.DialerText = dialer.Text;
        if(!bw1.IsBusy)
        bw1.RunWorkerAsync(listobj);
     }
 void bw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var digitMap = new Dictionary<int, string>() {
    { 1, "" },
    { 2, "[abcABC]" },
    { 3, "[defDEF]" },
    { 4, "[ghiGHI]" },
    { 5, "[jklJKL]" },
    { 6, "[mnoMNO]" },
    { 7, "[pqrsPQRS]" },
    { 8, "[tuvTUV]" },
    { 9, "[wxyzWXYZ]" },
    { 0, "" },
};
            var enteredDigits = DialerText;
            var charsAsInts = enteredDigits.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString()));
            var regexBuilder = new StringBuilder();

            foreach (var val in charsAsInts)
            regexBuilder.Append(digitMap[val]);
            MainPage.pattern = regexBuilder.ToString();

            MainPage.pattern = ".*" + MainPage.pattern + ".*";

            var listobj = (ListObjectType)e.Argument;
            e.Result = listobj.FindAll(x => x.PhoneNumbers.Any(a=>a.Contains(MainPage.DialerText)) | Regex.IsMatch(x.FirstName, MainPage.pattern));
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            //  MessageBox.Show(f.Message);
        }

    }
void bw1_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        SearchListbox.ItemsSource = (IEnumerable<ListObjectItemType>)e.Result;
    }
```

NB - you'll obviously need to replace the casts to ListObjectType, and ListObjectItemType with the actual types!

Comment: It doesn't give any output, so I guess BackgroundWorkder can't get access to the SearchListbox.Itemsource property

Comment: Sorry @thewarri0r9 , you're right, you can't update a UI control in the BackGroundWorker.DoWork event handler (not without messing around anyway). I've updated the code above to do the actual update in the RunWorkerCompleted event handler, but you should note the actual regex testing is still done in the BackGroundWorker.DoWork event handler! NB theres some other really good answers here about a more efficient search - I was simply advising how to move the main work to the background thread!

Comment: The ConcurrentDictionary object may help too. It's a more thread-safe version of the Dictionary object.